# Adding Tags around h1 tags and all content in between

Tags: php, html, tags

I have some code which follows the order as below -

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Text here</p>
<ul><li>maybe a list</li></ul>

<h1>Title 1</h1>
<p>More text here</p>
<h2>maybe a h2 somewhere</h2>
```

I am wondering if, with using PHP and/or jQuery, there is any way to wrap each h1 tag with a span tag and everything up until the next h1 tag (so the p, ul or h2 tag) in another span tag so I end up with something as below -

```
<span class="header"><h1>Title</h1></span>
<span class="content">
<p>Text here</p>
<ul><li>maybe a list</li></ul>
</span>

<span class="header"><h1>Title 1</h1></span>
<span class="content">
<p>More text here</p>
<h2>maybe a h2 somewhere</h2>
</span>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - Should have added before that the whole text comes from a database as one row of data.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just wrap the h1 in a span?

Comment: @MCMXCII I think OP means at runtime.

Comment: @MCMXCII Unfortunately, I have a lot of data which is already in a database and would like to find a way to do it all without having to edit each record.

Comment: HTML forbids h1 elements appearing inside span elements.

Comment: You should use div instead

Comment: @Quentin Sorry I was using span tags as an example - It wouldn't be span that I am using.

Comment: If you're loading data from a database and then outputting it to a page using php, you could look at using regex to identify anything between a h1 tag and output that in a wrapped h1, that could be one way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a similar code with python and beautiful soup and it's quite easy if you traverse your html with a tree.

you could use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Parse the html :

```
$html = str_get_html('<h1>Title</h1><p>Text here</p><ul><li>maybe a list</li></ul><h1>Title 1</h1><p>More text here</p><h2>maybe a h2 somewhere</h2>');
```

then find all  the h1 tags :

```
foreach($html->find('h1') as $element)
```

Wrap it with your span (or div maybe ?) in a new tag, and find the next h1 as you add all (and delete from the tree) the sibling that are not h1 into this new tag.

```
$element->next_sibling()
...
```

Then replace the original h1 by the new tags you have created.

Hope this helps